# How to use redux-thunk correctly, with React?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to get my app not to complain that action does not have an undefined type property.

I have set up my client side render as follows:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import routes from './shared/routes';
import rootReducer from './shared/reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

let initialState = window.__INITIAL_STATE_;

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    {routes}
</Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Which I believed to be the correct way?

Comment: Do you know that redux-thunk only checks if the action if a function and if it is, then it calls that function?

Comment: Yes, you can call a function as opposed to an object containing a type and a payload. My code appears to be tripping up on calls using dispatch(myAction()) inside that function. If that makes any sense at all? My code can be found here: https://github.com/designspin/react-redux-universal

Comment: What types of actions do you want to make? In general you'll use thunks to dispatch async actions.

Comment: Yes I am using Fetch to query my api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In the [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) github page there's a great example of how to use it.

For your actions, if it's an async action, I'm using this approach to dispatch an async action with promises:

Action:

```js
export function add({name, time}) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: ADD});
    return postJSON('/api/services', {
      name,
      time,
    })
    .then(service => {
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_SUCCESS,
        service: service,
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_FAILURE,
        error,
      });
    });
  };
}
```

Inside my component:

```
  addService () {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
      return (fields) => {
        dispatch(add(fields));
        dispatch(toggleAddForm());
      };
  }
```

Comment: The full source code that you can see as an example of a simple project, it's here: https://github.com/francorisso/hairdresser

Comment: So I can't actually do this? Put a function inside dispatch, like dispatch(loginUserRequest()). You can see my actions here: https://github.com/designspin/react-redux-universal/blob/master/src/shared/actions/index.js

Comment: @Jason you are doing the same thing right? Create action creators which return a function, right? So basically the way it should work is actions creators should return functions which thunk takes care of  and last action creator in chain should return a plain object. So i guess you are doing it correctly.

Comment: Okay guys, thanks for all your help. It turns out because I was using a function to create Constants they were out of scope and coming back undefined. So yes for the question I was asking this was correct, just so happened that the problem was due to something elsewhere! Just had to spend a bit of time in the debugger to get to the bottom of it! I will mark Franco as the correct answer.